# Calculate total revenue

Tags: arithmetic

[image]

I need help on this question. Thanks in advance!

my calculation is like this:
Percentage difference: 31-27=4

4% = £50,000
100% = £1.25mil

Need to find total revenue:
Profit = Revenue - Cost
Not too sure about this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

- (1) $revenue*0.27 = profit$
- (2) $revenue*0.31 = salaries$
- (3) $profit + 50000 = salaries$ (since salaries has higher allocated %)

You can substitute the left side of (3) for $salaries$ in (2), then solve for $profit$:

- $revenue*0.31 = profit + 50000$
- $profit = revenue*0.31 - 50000$

Now, set this and (1) equal to each other and solve for $revenue$

- $revenue*0.31 - 50000 = revenue*0.27$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%2a0.31+-+50000+%3D+r%2a0.27) says revenue is about 1,250,000

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, homework ;)

- Sanity check year 3: 20%+22%+31%+27% = 100%
- Salaries: 31%, Profit: 27%. Salaries - Profit = 4%.
- 4% -> 50k GBP
- Question reformulated: if 4% are 50k GBP, how much are 100%?

Comment: £1.25mil for 100%, so may I know how to find revenue?

it's a numerical test that I am preparing for interview :(

Comment: I'd say that "allocation of sales revenue" on top just might mean: "this is how our revenue was distributed". So, in my mind, 100% would be your answer.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. 100% would be £1.25mil, there's no options for this answer.

Comment: Judging from the comma to separate the thousands in your posted picture, there is a 0 missing at the 4th answer. Which then should be the correct one. Kick the programmer ;)

Answer (score 0):

So what was the percentage difference between profit and salaries that year?